# Property Injection with AutoFixture

Tags: autofixture

I've been fighting with the following issue for a day or so now. Despite having used AutoFixture for years, I can't get my head around this issue.

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass 
{
   public IChildClass Child {get; set;}
};
```

The IChildInterface:

```
public interface IChildClass
{
   string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The implementation of the interface:

```
public class ChildClass : IChildClass
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I then have a derived class of AbstractClass:

```
public class MyClass : AbstractClass
{
   public MyClass()
   {
      Initialize();
   }

   private void Initialize()
   {
      var nameOfChild = Child.Name;
   }
}
```

In my unit test for MyClass I do the following:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

var sut = fixture.Create<MyClass>();
```

But get an NullReferenceException on Child.Name. I've tried using Register and Customize for IChildClass and AbstractClass, no luck. Even a custom implementation of ISpecimenBuilder, doesn't help in this case.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to get around this?

Comment: If you forget about AutoFixture for a moment, how would you expect this to work?

Comment: I would mark the IChildClass property of AbstractClass with the Unity [Dependency] attribute, and inject it.

Comment: Have you tried just going `var sut = new MyClass();` and see what happens?

Comment: Sure, that would solve this, but quite cumbersome to build test data in the object graph. I actually solved this by changing Initialize to a property, and rename it. Then I could go with Build<>(): `var sut = fixture.Build<MyClass>().Without(x => x.Initialize).Create();`

Comment: What I meant is: have you actually *tried* to compile and run the code presented here? AFAICT, there's no way it could ever work.

Comment: No, that's my point. In the actual setup, IChildClass is property injected via Unity to work. So, my question is how do I make AutoFixture come around this?

Comment: How is that possible? The property can't possibly be assigned before the constructor has executed. What would the Unity code look like?

Comment: My bet. I can see your point. What I didn't include was the little detail that it is actually Unity, that also creates MyClass.

Comment: How does that make a difference? The `MyClass` constructor is attempting to read the `Child` property, which isn't initialized at that point... Of course it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a smart-ass here; I'd like to help, but unless I'm missing out on something, I can't see how you could expect this to ever work. I copied all your code into VS, and attempted to create an instance of MyClass, and as expected it throws an exception. It may just be that I'm being extremely dull here, but I can't see how it could possibly work as presented here. It doesn't really matter whether you use `new`, AutoFixture or Unity...

Comment: Let me get back to you, I'm quite hung up these days...

Answer (score 1):

The above code will never work because *Initialize* gets called in the Ctor.  Autofixture is initializing the object and the property hasn't been injected just as yet.  There are several work arounds for the above but as it stands... *Child* will always be null in the Initialize method.